Fail to create BrowserContext through raw CDP in Puppeteer
I am trying to create a new browserContext in a headless Chrome by issuing raw CDP commands. Looking at the documentation of the CDP Protocol it seems straightforward enough: issue a Target.createBrowserContext command. When I issue the command I get the following error:
{"id":2,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Not allowed"}}

I've tried to see how Puppeteer does it by logging the messages it sends on different commands. When using browser.createBrowserContext() a new context is created successfully. When trying the same thing manually a few lines below, the call fails.
Some sample code to reproduce:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async ()=>{
    console.log("STARTING BROWSER");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:["--remote-allow-origins=*"]});
    console.log("STARTING CONTEXT");
    const context = await browser.createBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    const cdp = await page.createCDPSession();
    await cdp.send("Target.createBrowserContext");
})();


Why do you want to do this with raw CDP, out of curiosity?

I have an web crawler that is based on Selenium. I'm trying to explore whether I can use Contexts instead of Browsers for the lessened impact on memory usage.
The SDK in my backend language does not support Contexts, so I had to resort to raw CDP.
I was experimenting with Puppeteer since it was faster to take a look at the exact underlying message than using the Protocol Monitor in the browser.

Target.createBrowserContext is only available from browser target sessions.
The following should work in Puppeteer:
const cdp = await browser.target().createCDPSession();
await cdp.send("Target.createBrowserContext");

